# ASP.NET RegularExpressionValidator does not validate for different number of digits allowed

Tags: asp.net, regex

I have a RegulareExpressionValidator that only validates for 3 digits only condition:

`<asp.regularexpressionvalidator ...ValidationExpression="\d{3}"></asp:regularexpressionvalidator>`

I need it to be able to validate for 3 and 5 digits only.

I tried to use `\d{3,5}` and `\d{3}\d{5}` and `[0-9]{3}|[0-9]{5}`.

Nothing seems to be working.

What is the right way to do it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to use anchors. Anchors helps to do an exact match.. Below regex would match three or 5 digit number only.

```
^(?:[0-9]{3}|[0-9]{5})$
```

`^` asserts that we are at the start where `$` asserts that we are at the end. Your regex `\d{3,5}` would match three or four or 5 digits. `{min,max}` called repeatation quantifier which repeats the previous token from three to 5 times.